# Hibernate Interceptor

Tags: c#, hibernate, onload, interceptor

The onload brings only the id of the entity, and the other properties are null.

I need to validate whether or not the entity sampling, depending on the values ​​of certain properties of the IAccount.  Here is my code so far:

```
public bool OnLoad(object entity, object id, System.Collections.IDictionary state)
{
    IAccount account = (IAccount)entity;
    account.xxxxxx        
    return true;
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

OnLoad happens before the entity object is actually initialized, so "entity" will have default property values, as you have already seen.  The way you evaluate or alter the state of the entity is through the "state" being passed in.

Your example isn't very specific about what you are trying to evaluate, but let us pretend you wish to perform some logging if the IsSampling property of your IAccount is false:

```
public bool OnLoad(object entity, object id, System.Collections.IDictionary state)
{
    var isSampling = state["IsSampling"] as bool?;

    if( entity is IAccount && isSampling.HasValue )
    {
        if( !isSampling )
            Log.Write( string.Format( "Sampling for Account with id {0} is not active", id ) );
    }

    return false;
}
```

Note also that I am returning false, to indicate that the state of the entity has not been altered.  If you want to change the state of the entity, you must do so through the state collection passed in (not through the entity object being passed in), and you must return true.

It can be difficult finding documentation that covers this, but here is one source (though it is a little outdated): [NHibernate.IInterceptor](http://elliottjorgensen.com/nhibernate-api-ref/NHibernate/IInterceptor.html#M%3aNHibernate.IInterceptor.OnLoad%28System.Object,System.Object,System.Object%5B%5D,System.String%5B%5D,NHibernate.Type.IType%5B%5D%29)